# When TLS and SSL are different and TLS is new compared to SSL, why the IIS doen't show specific settings for enalbing tls

Tags: ssl, iis

Unable to find specific setting for enabling/disabling tls on iis. Is Enabling/Disabling ssl the same as enabling/disabling tls?

I have gone through the few blogs and found that the SSL is predecessor of TLS and SSL older versions are deprecated. But i was uanble to find any specific settings for TLS

Comment: There are tools like for example [this one](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) which allows you to disable specific version of TLS and SSL, however as far as I know disabling SSL in the IIS admin tools will disable all versions and also disable TLS.

Comment: The naming can be confusing. There is the protocol family formerly known as SSL and today known as TLS  (or also SSL/TLS) and there are specific versions like SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 .. TLS 1.3. Unless a specific version is mentioned it is likely that the whole protocol family is meant, i.e. support for SSL/TLS means in the context of HTTP the support for HTTPS.

Comment: Like Steffen commented, you must get used to the SSL/TLS naming convention. Even though SSL v1-v3 are now obsolete, nobody is going to rename HTTPS (HTTP over SSL) to HTTP over TLS. In IIS's case, when a setting says SSL you should understand it as SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS is the successor to SSL.HTTPS, or "HTTP Secure," is an application-specific implementation that is a combination of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) with the SSL/TLS. HTTPS is used to provide encrypted communication with and secure identification of a Web server.

To enable/disable TLS and SSL you could use one of the below ways:

1)by using registry changes

2)using IIS Crypto

1)Registry setting:

- Open registry on your server by running ‘regedit‘ in the Run window and
  navigate to the below location.

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols**

- Add the TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 keys under Protocols.

[image]

- create two keys Client and Server under both TLS keys.
- create the DWORD Values under Server and Client key as following:

  DisabledByDefault [Value = 0]

  Enabled [Value = 1]

to disable you could use :

DisabledByDefault [Value = 0]

Enabled  [Value = 0]

[image]

after doing registry changes you need to restart the server.

2)IIS Crypto:

by using  IIS Crypto you just need to install the extension and check and uncheck the protocol version.you could also enable and disable ciphers, hashes, and key exchange algorithms.

[image]

Download link:

[IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/)

you could use a [network monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=4865) to check which protocol version is used by the site.